# Gridview row updating button not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datagridview

My gridview row updating button is not working when I press edit and then press on the button to apply the changes it doesn't do anything. Am I missing something?

My code looks like this

**C#**

```
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    string afspraak = ((TextBox)(GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("EditAfspraak"))).Text;
    string uitleg = ((TextBox)(GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("EditUitleg"))).Text;
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(((TextBox)(GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("EditID"))).Text);
    _controller.RecordUpdatenTblAfspraken(afspraak, uitleg, id);
}

protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
}

protected void GridView1_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
}
```

**ASP.NET**

Couldn't paste it correctly so it's here:

https://pastebin.com/S3S09nLL

**Highlighted button isn't working**
[image]

Comment: are you binding the gridview inside (!Page.IsPostBack)??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to rebind the grid after you change the `EditIndex`.

```
protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;

    GridView1.DataSource = mijnDatabaseBron;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

The same goes for `GridView1_RowCancelingEdit` and when update has succeeded in `GridView1_RowUpdating`. This is assuming you added the `OnRowEditing`, `OnRowCancelingEdit` and `OnRowUpdating` events to the GridView.

Also as `user7415073` commented, the binding of the GridView must be inside an `IsPostBack` check.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        GridView1.DataSource = mijnDatabaseBron;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

And see my answer here as to how you can easily pass the `EditID` to code behind.

[Get old value of label inside GridView during RowUpdating (ASP.NET GridView) C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43634813/get-old-value-of-label-inside-gridview-during-rowupdating-asp-net-gridview-c-s/43635036#43635036)